# Symfony & VueJS - Encore

Tags: vue.js, symfony, yarnpkg, symfony5, webpack-encore

I'm using VueJS in my Symfony 5.2.1 project with Webpack-encore and yarn.

Some hours ago, when I updated my code, I used to do "yarn encore dev" and modifications was applied.

But now, when I run "yarn encore dev", I have no errors but my page is always the same...

I tried "yarn cache clean" but nothing happens.

Do you have an idea of the problem?

Comment: Did you check "public/build" folder? is there any changes in it?

Answer (score 1):

It worked after rename the Build folder into « buildOld » and « « yarn encore dev ».

I should try another browser that’s a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try one these:

1. Press Ctrl+U on page (using Chrome), find .js files, connected to page, open them in new tabs and press Ctrl+R on each.
2. Try different browser
3. Try to clear public/build folder in your project directory and then re-run `yarn encore dev`